# Deactivate a System Administrator without losing the dashboards they built

Tags: administration

Just came onboard with a new company and had a request to deactivate the old system administrator, which I did. However, that sys admin had created dashboards for each of the sales people using reports the sales teams had built. When I deactivated the system admin, all of the dashboards he had built we no longer available. I had to reactivate his account to bring the dashboards back. What can I do to deactivate this system admins account without losing the dashboards he built?

Answer (score 2):

Pull up all dashboards listing the old admin as the running user. Click edit and change 'View Dashboard as' to an active user(in this case an admin).

Comment: Forgot to add to grab a cup of coffee...     But in all seriousness, this is just one of those crappy things that you get to deal with.  You could attempt to try doing something through Eclipse to see if you can change the Running User there.  My suggestion would be to keep him active and Frozen as you're doing this clean-up.

Comment: Thanks, David. Yep, that's what I did to bring the dashboards back (activate and freeze). I'll take a look and see how many there are and if it turns out to be a significant number, think I will grab that cup of coffee first. Thanks again.